# Does the application with heavy use of generic classes have slower startup time than the same application with non-generic classes

Tags: c#, .net, performance

It is already known the benefits of using generic class vs non-generic class in terms in performance. Avoiding casts give better performance but instantiation of generic classes involve runtime overhead of emitting IL code for the generic class for specific type T and then JIT this code. This leads me to the conclusion that I am trading startup application performance for better performance later.

Also, I would like to know how generics play with ahead-of-time compilation, like NGEN. I assume generic classes cannot be ahead-of-time compiled, but non-generic classes can. Would that lead to an additional hit on the startup performance of the application, if generic classes need to be JITted, but non-generic classes do not?

Additionally, any insights or information on how NativeAOT works with generics would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just try out with a benchmark?

Comment: That is hard to be benchmarked. BenchmarkDotNet have warm up cycles which will cause emit of generic class IL to be outside the actual measurement in the warm up steps. I could write a test app with hundred of generic classes, which would be required to actually spot any difference, but that is not worth the time if someone have the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no proof, but I think the impact is negligible. The compiler (whether ahead of time or during jit) needs to translate the same concrete class exactly once. When using generics, that means that (unless some internal optimizations apply) `List<string>` and `List<int>` are two different classes that need to be translated separately, but multiple instances of `List<string>` are the same type.

So that may mean that starting an application that uses a lot of different `List<T>` types takes a tiny bit more time to start than one that consists of `ArrayList` only. But the performance impact of all the required casts in the later case is certainly a lot higher, not to mention the compile-time type safety. And you won't gain anything if you create `ListOfString` and `ListOfInt` types all over the place - these are still separate types.

Comment: I agree in general that the overhead of generic classes shouldn't be reason to choose between generic and non-generic but I do not agree that overhead is negligible especially in the context of ahead of time compilation. We see huge benefit of NGEN - like 5x times faster startup time between non-NGENed app and NGENed. If generic classes are not eligible for NGEN (as I suspect but I am not sure),  that means huge part of our code is not NGENed and we could have even more benefit from NGEN during startup.

Comment: @ekalchev That would apply if you only NGEN the libraries, but not the application using the generic classes. I don't know whether it's done that way (since I don't know the implementation of NGEN), but as soon as the concrete type is known, it can be compiled. So if you use NGEN on the whole application, all classes should have been compiled (except when using dynamic types, reflection or the like, of course)